# Raspberry Pi Cuts Off /etc/rc.local

Tags: linux, bash, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I have the following code in `/etc/rc.local` on a Raspberry Pi 2 running Raspbian:

```
for i in `seq 1 10`;
do
    echo $i
    sleep 1
done
```

I expect this to count to 10 slowly in the opening text. It does not.
To test that `/etc/rc.local` runs on startup, I put this in it:

```
mkdir /home/pi/THISWORKS
```

This works. A folder named `THISWORKS` appears in my home directory.
To test that it does output to the starting text, I changed the original code to:

```
for i in `seq 1 10`;
do
    echo "THISWORKS"
done
```

I see ten "THISWORKS"s appear at the end of the start text before starting the GUI.
I think that the system gives `/etc/rc.local` some time to work in the startup text, but then cuts it off at a certain point. To test this theory, I put this into `/etc/rc.local`:

```
sleep 100
mkdir THISWORKS
```

Now when it starts up, I don't see the folder `THISWORKS` in my home directory. However, after 100 seconds, I do see it.

## How do I give `/etc/rc.local` time to do its thing?

Edit: How do I make Xorg wait for `/etc/rc.local` to finish?

Comment: It does the thing, just Xorg starts parallel with rc.local, so if you switch back to console, you'll see the numbers.

Comment: How do I make it wait instead of starting in parallel?

Comment: The easiest way is starting X at the bottom of rc.local.